# what is pandas rolling window

Tags: pandas, correlation, series, rolling-computation

I am trying to understand how rolling window works in the case of correlation between series.

For the example let's take two series :

```
se1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

se2 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1])
```

I would like to compute the rolling(2) correlation between these series.

These two solutions seem to work :

```
se1.rolling(3).corr(se2)
se1.rolling(3).corr(se2.rolling(3))
```

But this one doesn't work :

```
se1.corr(se2.rolling(3))
```

Could you explain why ?
How can I represent the rolling windows in this case. Is

```
se1.rolling(3) =
. NAn
. NAn
. [1,2,3]
. [2,3,4]
. [4,5,6]
...
```

?

Then how this could match the se2 dim (in the 1st solutions above) ?

Comment: What are you expecting from this: `se1.corr(se2.rolling(3))`? The `corr` method for series returns 1 number, the correlation for all observations.

Comment: I am expecting correlation for matching indexes, as for se1.rolling(3).corr(se2). 
I thought that it is excatly the same to do serie1.corr(serie2) and serie2.corr(serie1)